# Access denied to users accounts at the Joomla frontend, "Feature Disabled"

Tags: forms, authentication, joomla, frontend

When a user try to enter to own account the system answer: "Feature Disabled". And it doesn´t happen in this page.

I am using Joomla 5.02 and PHP 8.2

Does anybody help me in order to configure the Plugins & Modules?

Or write the right code or

Fix any files?

Answer (score 0):

This error does not come from the Joomla core, which means that this error is caused by one of the following:

- A third party extension
- An .htaccess rule
- Some code in the defines.php file

Check your third party extensions, especially security and community extensions that you have and see if it's any of them. If not, check the .htaccess file and then the defines.php file.

If you have access to the shell, try using grep to search for "Feature Disabled" - this will likely identify the culprit (you can also search the database for such an entry).